# PHPBB Order Forums by Post/Topic Date

Tags: php, forum, phpbb3

I'm new to PHPbb but I had this great idea but I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

What I want to have is a "Category" which contains multiple forums inside - Pretty easy.  But, I would like it if the forums could be programed so that they automatically order themselves based on which forums topic has been updated the most recent, as opposed to setting it manually. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not without using a MOD (for 3.0.x) or extension (for 3.1.x), which is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. Your best bet would be to request a mod or extension in the relevant section of phpbb.com